# How to type props in styled-components react-native component?

Tags: typescript, react-native, styled-components

How can I use the `Props` interface to type my react native `Text` component props with styled components?

When I do it like this I don't get any props typing when using the component.

```
type TypeScaleVariant =
  | 'displayLarge'
  | 'displayMedium'
  | 'bodyLarge'
  | 'bodyMedium'

type ContentColor =
  | 'onSurface'
  | 'onSurfaceVariant'
  | 'primary'
  | 'error'

interface Props {
  variant?: TypeScaleVariant;
  color?: ContentColor;
}

const Typography = styled.Text<Props>(
  ({ theme, variant = 'bodyMedium', color = 'onSurface' }) => ({
    ...theme.typescale[variant],
    color: theme.color[color],
  })
);


export default Typography;
```

However I do get props types when filling default props types inside the component file.

I expect to get type safety and suggestions in props but I have to manually fill them in:

```
<Typography variant='displayLarge' color='error'>
 Hello world
</Typography>
```

Comment: What error do you get when "when filling default props types inside the component file." ?

Comment: If you default value for `variant` in the component itself, there's no need to supply default-value in the style like you do --> `variant = 'bodyMedium``

Comment: I don't use `.defaultProps` anymore. What I meant was the default values in the component function attributes

Comment: There is no error, I expect to see all `variant` or `color` types suggested by IDE when using instance of `Typography` component elsewhere but I don't get any suggestions or any type safety when using the instance.

Comment: Suggestions should appear once you remove single-quotes an you re-type it